# Как правильно использовать std::begin и std::end?

Tags: c++, c++11

Начиная с С++11, в стандарт были добавлены функции `std::begin` и `std::end`, которые можно использовать вместо методов `.begin()` и `.end()`.

Как и когда их надо использовать?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Наиболее известное свойство функций `std::begin` и `std::end` - это то, что они работают с массивами:

```
int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
int sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 0);
```

Для контейнеров-классов, если тип контейнера известен, единственное преимущество свободной функции std::begin() перед функцией-членом - это то, что код получается на один символ короче:

```
std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};
std::reverse(begin(v), end(v));
std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Здесь префикс `std::` указывать не надо, т.к. работает поиск имен, зависящих от аргументов (ADL): `vector` находится в пространстве имен `std`, по этому для него будет найдена функция `std::begin` (из того же пространства имен).

---

**В обобщенном коде надо использовать `using std::begin;`**

Так как существует поиск имен (ADL), то нужные функции `begin` и `end` могут находиться в другом пространстве имен (не `std`). Однако с массивами работают только функции из `std`, по этому в шаблонных функциях надо явно добавлять `std::begin` и `std::end` в область видимости:

```
template<typename Container>
int sum(Container& c) {
    using std::begin; // Поиск имен также будет искать std::begin.
    using std::end;
    return std::accumulate(begin(c), end(c), 0);
}
```

Если сюда передать контейнер-класс, который находится в каком-либо пространстве имен, то будут использованы функции `begin()` и `end()` из этого пространства имен.
Если же таких функций нет, или `Container` - это обычный массив, то будут вызваны функции `std::begin` и `std::end`. Для контейнеров-классов будут вызваны методы `.begin()` и `.end()`.

Это можно продемонстрировать следующим примером ([Код полностью](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c99aea26516c0f7a))

```
struct GlobalArray {
    ...
    int* begin() { return arr; }
    int* end() { return arr + N; }
};

namespace ns {
    struct Array {...};    
    int* begin(Array& a);
    int* end(Array& a);
}

int main() {
    ns::Array ns_arr;
    for (auto& x : ns_arr) x = 1;
    // В sum() будут использованы ns::begin и ns::end
    std::cout << sum(ns_arr) << '\n';

    std::vector<int> v = {1, 20, 300};
    // Будут использованы std::begin и std::end, которые вызовут методы .begin() и .end()
    std::cout << sum(v) << '\n';

    int c_arr[] = {400, 50, 6};
    // Будут использованы std::begin и std::end
    std::cout << sum(c_arr) << '\n';

    GlobalArray glob_arr;
    for (auto& x : glob_arr) x = 1;
    // Будут использованы std::begin и std::end, которые вызовут методы .begin() и .end()
    std::cout << sum(glob_arr) << '\n';
}
```